# How can I check for identical values in dictionary keys and then return the keys with those identical values?

Tags: python

I need to check a dictionary for keys whos values are identical and then return the keys that have identical values.

My code is below:

```
count = {}
x = "Helllo Worldddd5!"

for s in x.lower():
    if s == ' ' or s.isdigit() or s in '!@#$%^&*()></?:"':
        continue
    elif s in count.keys():
        count[s] += 1
    else:
        count[s] = 1
```

which results in:

```
count = {'e': 1, 'd': 4, 'o': 2, 'h': 1, 'w': 1, 'l': 4, 'r': 1}
```

As you can see 'd' and 'l' have identical values. I want to iterate through the key/value pairs and return the keys that have identical values. I want to return 'h' and 'l' in this case.

Comment: _"As you can see 'h' and 'l' have identical values."_ I don't understand. H's value is 1, and L's value is 4. They don't seem identical to me.

Comment: `s in count` would be better than using `count.keys()` and as kevin has commented h and l seem to have nothing in common

Comment: Also  `collections.Counter([ele.lower() for ele in x if ele.isalpha()])`  will most probably do what your code is trying to do

Answer (score 3):

You could make a `set` of the unique `count` values. Then check which keys have those values in a dict comprehension.

```
count = {'e': 1, 'd': 4, 'o': 2, 'h': 1, 'w': 1, 'l': 4, 'r': 1}
s = set(count.values())
d = {j : [i for i in count if count[i] == j] for j in s}

>>> d
{1: ['e', 'h', 'r', 'w'],
 2: ['o'],
 4: ['d', 'l']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

counts = Counter([ele.lower() for ele in x if ele.isalpha()]).most_common()
print [list(val[0] for val in list(v))for k, v in groupby(counts, key=lambda t: t[1])]

[['d', 'l'], ['o'], ['e', 'h', 'r', 'w']]
```